# Trace is a multiple of determinant in congruence subgroups of Modular Group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, number-theory

An element of the [congruence subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congruence_subgroup) of order $n$ of the [modular group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_group) looks like this:

$M'= \begin{pmatrix} 
An+1 & Bn \\
Cn & Dn+1 
\end{pmatrix}$

with $A, B, C, D, n \in \mathbb{Z},$ and $n>0$.

If you use the property that the det($M')=1$, we get the following (assuming $n>0$):

$(AD-BC)n = A + D$

If we let $M=\begin{pmatrix} 
A & B \\
C & D 
\end{pmatrix}$, then the identity says that $n\cdot$det$(M)=A+D=$Tr($M$). Does this ring any bells for anyone? This identity is quite curious to me, although I have very little intuition for what it means. Perhaps someone can enlighten me.

Comment: Haven't you already ask a short time ago a similar question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There’s a similar calculation in Lie theory, and this would be a discrete version of it.

If you take an element $A$ of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$, then the corresponding one-parameter group of the Lie group $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is given by $A’=e^{tA}$, $t\in \mathbb{R}$. A truncated version of this (i.e. truncating the Taylor series) would be $A’=I+tA$. Note this approximation only works for $t$ small. In your case you have $M’=I+nM$. The fact that in $SL_2$, $\mathrm{det}(e^{tA})=1$ implies (taking derivatives of both sides) that $\mathrm{tr}(A)=0$. In your case you get $\mathrm{tr}(M)=n\mathrm{det}(M)$, which would approach $0$ as $n\to 0$.

Comment: Exactly. Very good. :)